# "Skew-dimension" and discrete parallelepipeds

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

Let $(G,+)$ be an abelian group. Given a subset $B\subseteq G\setminus\{0\}$, define the "discrete span" of $B$, which I will denote $\langle B\rangle_d$, to be the set of all $\sum A$ for $A$ a finite, non-empty subset of $B$. So, for example, if $B=\{a,b\}$ for some distinct $a,b$, then $\langle B\rangle_d=\{a,b,a+b\}$. Say that a subset $P\subseteq G$ is a "(discrete) parallelepiped of dimension $k$" if it is equal to $\langle B\rangle_d$ for some $B\subseteq G\setminus\{0\}$ of size $k$. Finally, given $A\subseteq G$, define the "skew-dimension" of $A$, which I will denote $\dim_s(A)$, to be the maximal $k$ such that $A$ contains a parallelepiped of dimension $k$. (If $A$ contains parallelepipeds of unbounded dimension, write $\dim_s(A)=\infty$.) So, for example, for $A\subseteq G\setminus\{0\}$ we have $A\hat{+}A\cap A=\varnothing$ if and only if $\dim_s(A)<2$, where $\hat{+}$ is the [restricted sumset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset).

I am writing very simply to ask whether this notion of "skew-dimension" has been investigated in the literature at all, either in the general context I describe or in a more specific context. My broader context for the question is model-theoretic, and hence rather off-topic, so I am not cluttering the question with those details; if others would prefer the details I am happy to add them to the question.